# simple_form_for edit page with nested resource routes in namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, form-helpers

I have nested resources routes defined under namespace, I am trying to make my edit form work. My create new form is working fine with just the following:

```
 <%= simple_form_for([:admin, @store, @newsletter], :as => :newsletter,
 :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

I have defined following routes as shown below:

```
namespace 'admin' do 
  resources :storefronts do
    resources :newsletter_registrations
  end
end
```

Does any one have any idea, How can I make my edit form work?

Thanks in Advance,
Mayank

Comment: Have you started an edit form? Can you show what you've tried and what problem you're encountering?